# Stray characters in source code - added when typing fast

Tags: macos, character-encoding, keyboard, character

I program on a Mac, and one of the most frequent compiler errors I get is the following:

```
src/cpp/scd/SelSCAN.cpp:122:2: error: stray '\240' in program
src/cpp/scd/SelSCAN.cpp:126:4: error: stray '\302' in program
```

This occurs apparently sometimes when I type the `{` and `|` special characters. If I retype these characters carefully, the error disappears, but if I type fast it happens to me all the time. Maybe I hit a combination of keys that produces this, though I do not really know what my fingers do. They have a mind of their own and work too fast for me to check. I can't switch it off mentally/physically, so I wonder if there is a way to avoid this technically. What are these strange stray invisible characters anyway?

This happens with both [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) and [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)).

PS: I am using a [QWERTZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ), (i.e. German) keyboard layout, in case it matters.

Comment: What text editor or IDE are you using to type your code? Have you considered switching to one that works, instead?

Comment: @Wooble This happens with both Sublime Text and Atom, which work very well for me, so I'd be loath to abandon them. What makes you think it is the fault of the editor?

Comment: They are a `non-breaking space` and a `capital A with circumflex accent` I believe.

Comment: What encoding? \302 is normally a signature (\342 is also common) for the start of a UTF-8 sequence. And 302 240 (octal) → 0xC2 0xA0 (hexadecimal) is the UTF-8 sequence for the very common Unicode code point U+00A0 ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=156&number=128)). It seems like too much of a coincidence.

Comment: If it was UTF-8 and NO-BREAK SPACE there would be two "Error: stray"s for each NO-BREAK SPACE character: two in line 122 and two in line 126 (error: stray '\302'. error: stray '\240' (in that order, and two times)).

Comment: *"[Non-breaking space characters ... on Mac, Option + Space makes one of those](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2021/06/01/when-a-space-is-not-a-space/)"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are a `non-breaking space` (\240) and a `capital A with circumflex accent` (\302), I believe.

This may help you disable them... [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces)

The keystroke for `capital A with circumflex` is Option+E, release, shift A.

If you can't disable them, you can maybe run this to remove them:

```
tr -d '\240\302' < yourfile
```

or this, to remove them and replace your existing file if it is successful

```
tr -d '\240\302' < yourfile > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp yourfile
```

Comment: I'm not sure yet. I need to write a bunch of lines of code to test whether the problem still occurs with the edited key bindings. Will get back to the question soon.

Comment: Editing the key bindings seems to have worked, thanks.